# Finding range for inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

$3(\arcsin(x))^2 + 2(\arccos(x))^2+7 =f(x)$

My attempt

I wrote $\arcsin(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos(x)$
Then I found max value of $f(x)$ 
Since.    $0<\arccos(x) <\pi$ 
For f max I made $\arccos(x) = \pi$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
Let $\arccos x=t$ and $t \in \left[ 0 \:\: \pi \right]$

Then we have  $$g(t)=3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)^2+2t^2+7$$

Maximize and Minimize $g(t)$ in $t \in \left[0 \: \:\pi \right]$

Comment: Respected sir by this we get f(x ) min = 3(pie)^2 + 28/4 and f(x) max = 11(pie)^2 + 28/4 , but the answer is wrong for f(x)min = 3(pie)^2+70/10. I don’t how can this be f(x) min

Comment: Mnimum value of $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ if $a \gt 0$ is given by $\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$

Comment: Thanks sir, the problem was with my knowledge of quadratic ☺️